Bluetooth connection issue when pairing Android app with Raspberry Pi
I'm working on an Android app that pairs with a Raspberry Pi-based Bluetooth device using the Bluetooth serial connection. I'm attempting to send notifications to the device once it's paired, but I am running into issues where the connection isn't established properly, and the Bluetooth device doesn't respond as expected.
It shows up on my Android Bluetooth settings, and when I click, it pairs without the need of a passkey, but then on the Pi, it shows no longer connected, but still paired on the phone, not connected.
Raspberry Pi Setup: I have configured the Raspberry Pi to be discoverable and pairable using the bluetoothctl commands, without a passkey, and it runs auto on boot: It is also set as a "Device" not a Host.
    bash
    Copy code
    sudo bluetoothctl
    power on
    agent NoInputNoOutput
    default-agent
    discoverable on
    pairable on

This is my FirstFragment Android Studio Java:

package com.aaadev.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.aaadev.myapplication.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button buttonSendNotification;

    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> deviceList;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList;
    private ListView listViewDevices;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "app_push_notification_channel";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable android.view.ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        buttonSendNotification = binding.buttonSendNotification;

        listViewDevices = binding.listViewDevices;
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Check Bluetooth permissions and list paired devices
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS);
            } else {
                listPairedDevices();
            }
        } else {
            listPairedDevices();
        }
        // Button click listener to send a push notification
        buttonSendNotification.setOnClickListener(v -> sendPushNotification());
        // ListView item click listener to select a device
        listViewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = pairedDevicesList.get(position);
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") String deviceName = selectedDevice.getName();

                if (deviceName != null && deviceName.contains("Pi")) {
                    // Start NotificationService and pass the device's address
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationService.class);
                    intent.putExtra("device_address", selectedDevice.getAddress());
                    getActivity().startService(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Connecting to " + deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected device is not a Pi device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void listPairedDevices() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    pairedDevicesList.add(device);
                    deviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);
                listViewDevices.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No paired devices found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bluetooth not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void sendPushNotification() {
        createNotificationChannel();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setContentTitle("New Push Notification")
                .setContentText("This is a push notification from YapYap!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPairedDevices();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bluetooth permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "App Push Notifications";
            String description = "Channel for app push notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}


Here is the Notification Sevrer.java:

    package com.aaadev.myapplication;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.UUID;

    public class NotificationService extends Service {

        private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "notification_service_channel";
        public static final String ACTION_CONNECTION_STATUS = "com.aaadev.myapplication.CONNECTION_STATUS";
        public static final String EXTRA_CONNECTION_SUCCESS = "connection_success";

        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            createNotificationChannel();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            String deviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra("device_address");
            if (deviceAddress != null) {
                new Thread(() -> connectToDevice(deviceAddress)).start(); // Run on background thread
            }

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Pi Notification Service")
                    .setContentText("Attempting to connect to Pi device...")
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                    .build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        private void connectToDevice(String address) {
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (!checkBluetoothPermission()) {
                Log.e("NotificationService", "Missing BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission.");
                broadcastConnectionStatus(false);
                stopSelf();
                return;
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            Log.d("NotificationService", "Attempting to connect to device: " + device.getName() + " (" + address + ")");

            try {
                Log.d("NotificationService", "Creating BluetoothSocket...");
                bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

                Log.d("NotificationService", "Connecting to BluetoothSocket...");
                bluetoothSocket.connect(); // Attempt to connect

                Log.d("NotificationService", "BluetoothSocket connected successfully!");
                outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

                // Broadcast success status
                broadcastConnectionStatus(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("NotificationService", "Connection failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                handleConnectionFailure();
            }
        }

        private boolean checkBluetoothPermission() {
            return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S ||
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }

        private void handleConnectionFailure() {
            if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("NotificationService", "Closing BluetoothSocket due to failure...");
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    Log.e("NotificationService", "Failed to close BluetoothSocket: " + closeException.getMessage(), closeException);
                }
            }

            broadcastConnectionStatus(false);
            stopSelf();
        }

        private void broadcastConnectionStatus(boolean success) {
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CONNECTION_STATUS);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CONNECTION_SUCCESS, success);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }

        private void createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Notification Service Channel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                if (manager != null) {
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
                if (bluetoothSocket != null) bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("NotificationService", "Error closing resources: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }



The "Pi" shows up on my listview and when i click it, it says Connecting on a toast, but this error throws:

    Attempting to connect to device: Pi (XX:XX:XX:D2:XX:XX)
    2024-12-15 13:53:42.781 27103-27156 NotificationService     com.aaadev.myapplication             D  Creating BluetoothSocket...
    2024-12-15 13:53:42.782 27103-27156 NotificationService     com.aaadev.myapplication             D  Connecting to BluetoothSocket...
    2024-12-15 13:53:42.782 27103-27156 BluetoothSocket         com.aaadev.myapplication             I  connect() for device XX:XX:XX:XX:5D:XX called by pid: 27103
    2024-12-15 13:53:47.172 27103-27196 ProfileInstaller        com.aaadev.myapplication             D  Installing profile for com.aaadev.myapplication
    2024-12-15 13:53:47.868 27103-27156 NotificationService     com.aaadev.myapplication             E  Connection failed: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
                                                                                                        java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
                                                                                                            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:1054)
                                                                                                            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:1068)
                                                                                                            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:583)
                                                                                                            at com.aaadev.myapplication.NotificationService.connectToDevice(NotificationService.java:74)
                                                                                                            at com.aaadev.myapplication.NotificationService.lambda$onStartCommand$0$com-aaadev-myapplication-NotificationService(NotificationService.java:43)
                                                                                                            at com.aaadev.myapplication.NotificationService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    2024-12-15 13:53:47.868 27103-27156 NotificationService     com.aaadev.myapplication             D  Closing BluetoothSocket due to failure...


I don't know why the Pi wont connect... I need to have it receive Push Notifications to the Pi from the phone from a foreground service / background service.
Let me know why this error is showing up.
Thanks in advance.

@Bravo apologies I just amended, was a typo. Thanks.

Unclear if you've seen this similar question: How to connect to Raspberry pi with an android app over bluetooth
